# Image not sizing Box with display:flex on safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari, display

I am trying to do a slider carousel in HTML and CSS and its working on Chrome. I fitted the image with display: flex and that's working on chrome, but on safari it does not work. The image is in its original size and not fitted to the the slider Box around it.

```css
.Potrait {
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 45%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80vmin;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 40rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  aspect-ratio: 3/4;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.slider img {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slider-nav {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.25rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.slider-nav a {
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity ease 250ms;
}

.slider-nav a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <section class="Potrait">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <div class="slider">
        <img id="slide-8" src="./Bilder/NYCB1.jpg" />
        <img id="slide-9" src="./Bilder/BusBVG.jpg" />
        <img id="slide-10" src="./Bilder/NYCB2.jpg" />
        <img id="slide-11" src="./Bilder/Lila.jpg" />
        <img id="slide-12" src="./Bilder/Oberbaum.jpg" />
        <img id="slide-13" src="./Bilder/Nyla.jpg" />
        <img id="slide-14" src="./Bilder/Niagara.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="slider-nav">
        <a href="#slide-8"></a>
        <a href="#slide-9"></a>
        <a href="#slide-10"></a>
        <a href="#slide-11"></a>
        <a href="#slide-12"></a>
        <a href="#slide-13"></a>
        <a href="#slide-14"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Already tried to google it but also the solutions did not help. Maybe someone knows what wrong with it, would be much appreciated :)

Comment: just set `img { max-width: 100% }`

Answer (score 0):

The Safari still doesn't support 100% HTML5 and CSS3, so some properties won't work...

Try to use, instead of flex, the -webkit-flex;